# How to overload a generic construtor

Tags: java, generics, constructor

I have a class `abc` as below

```
public class Abc<T> {
 int arg1;
 int arg2;
 int arg3;

  public <T> Abc(int arg1 , int arg2 ,int arg3){
   this.arg1 = arg1;
   this.arg2 = arg2;
   this.arg3 = arg3;
  }

 public <T> Abc(int arg1, int arg2){

 // How to call the above the constructor by setting some value to arg3.
 }
 }
```

How can I call the 3-argument from the 2-argument constructor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
public <T> Abc(int arg1, int arg2){
    this(arg1, arg2, 0);
}
```

You'll have to define a default value for `arg3`, I used `0` above.

Note: I think you don't need all those `<T>`

Comment: Yes. No need in <T> if it's not used inside constructor